# Variable Annuity - I want out, yes or no?

Tags: annuity

My sister bought a large annuity for me right after my husband passed away without my approval but now I am stuck! She no longer manages my money either and we don't talk because she really took advantage of me. I will be 59 1/2 this year and am wondering if I should dump it?? I am in year 6 of owning it.

I am also thinking of taking legal action against her company because I never approved her to take this money and sink it for 10 years. The surrender fees are hefty, about $20k and total surrender without penalty is 2024.

I am asking is it worth liquidating the whole thing and taking the hit or should I only take what I need (there is money available without surrender charges. If I take those funds out, where should I put them? Vanguard? Fidelity? I don't know where to find an investment advisor.

Comment: I'm sorry, there's nowhere near enough information to answer this question.

Comment: "Her company" - can you give more details? e.g. Is she an annuity salesman? Financial planner? Aside from 'sister', which may really become irrelevant, what is your financial relationship to her?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - not "policy" but I'd hope that if details are needed, we can try to ask for them, and give OP time (24 hrs?) to update their question. On reflection, this one may be a legal, rather than financial. But either way, the devil is in the details.

Comment: I dont understand, how did your sister get your money to buy this annuity? Did she steal it? Does she have a power of attorney? Does she work at your bank or is your financial adviser? Without information on how she took your money this isn't answerable.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably small solace but traditional variable annuities tend to have an annual no penalty withdrawal limit equal to the GRIP, GRUB, GMIB (deferred growth feature) or whatever any  particular insurance company calls it. It tends to be in the area of 5-6%.  Any such withdrawal is LIFO so the withdrawals are taxable until all gains are exhausted.

Again, small solace but surrender fees tend to diminish each year.  It's still a hit to surrender early, regardless of the year.

I wonder whether your sister has/had  Power of Attorney over your account? Did she require your approval for making financial decisions? Was this a managed money account? I think that this is more of a legal question than a financial one.

Comment: Thank you! II have read these annuities stink! My sister DID NOT have any POA or permission to sink my funds in this. It was done as a self-serving move for her to make money off me. She is a top advisor at Ameriprise!! I feel she totally took advantage of me, weeks after my husband's death.I want a portion to buy a house with and may have to pay the fees. I think it's time to contact an attorney to see if I have any options but that's going to be messy.

Comment: Eileen - I do not see any edit yet to the original question. If you don't clarify the relationship, literally the question of how she's managing your money, we can not help. And note, I edited out the words in your comment that add no value to the discussion.

Comment: If your sister did not have POA then how did she have access to your funds?

Comment: Hi, To be honest, I don't know. I was in shock after he passed. I did open an account with her however never gave her the permission to sink it in a 10-year annuity. Why would she have a POA? She also did some other things that were not very ethical but I have let them go. I will probably sell it, losing 20k, and take it somewhere else. It's a lot to lose but it's stuck at Ameriprise(Riversource) until 2024.

Comment: "Opened an account with her": what does that mean? If it was something like a joint checking account, any money in it was available to *either* of you to do with as you pleased; she wouldn't have needed your permission to buy the annuity. (You might have legal recourse against her, arguing you weren't of sound mind after your husband's death, though that might be a stretch. You could consult an attorney, at least.)

Comment: In order to buy an annuity, you have to sign a contract.  If you sister did not have POA and you did not sign a contract, then this becomes  a legal matter because that implies forgery.  I'd think twice about incurring the $20k penalty.  If the annuity is performing well, hang in there unless you need the money to survive.  Many annuities have withdrawal provisions where you can take out money and pay the penalty on the amount that exceeds the annual non penalty allowable withdrawal.  You need better advice than an anonymous finance BB.